This model of friction implies the speed decays exponentially, but shouldn't it actually vanish within a finite amount of time?
A snooker player strikes the cue ball, so that it starts moving with constant speed $v_{0}$. We assume that spin plays no role in its motion. Due to friction between the ball and the cloth of the snooker table, and between the ball and air molecules, the ball slows down until it comes to a standstill.
We can model the friction as a force $$F = -\alpha v(t).$$ Solving Newton's equations we get a formula for the speed as a function of time, $$v(t) = v_{0} \space exp(-\alpha t/m)$$ and a formula for the position as a function of time $$x(t)= mv_{0}/\alpha \space [1 - \exp(-\alpha t/m)].$$
These two formulas predict correctly that the initial speed is equal to the $v_{0}$, that the speed drops of due to friction and that there is maximum distance the snooker ball will travel. However, in my opinion there is a slight weakness in these formulas. They suggest that the decrease in speed is exponential, and therefore the ball keeps on moving however long one waits. In reality, the snooker ball comes to a standstill in a finite amount of time. I.e. there is a time $T$ after which everyone (players, referee) agrees that the ball is no longer moving. Therefore the friction law above can not be quite correct. The law may work well for sufficiently high speeds, but below a certain value the speed should drop to zero in a finite amount of time; for example linearly or quadratically in time. Is this correct?
Update. It has been suggested in the comments that it is better to model the friction as $F = -\mu mg$. Yes, I realize this might indeed be a better model because speed would then decrease linearly to a standstill, $v(t) = v_{0} - \mu gt$. I assume that the force (in vector form) can perhaps be written as:
$$F = -\mu mg \space (v_{x},v_{y})/ \sqrt{v_{x}^2 + v_{y}^2 + \epsilon ^2}$$
where $\epsilon$ is a small parameter. In this form the expression for the force is continuous and analytical when the velocity is zero.

Your model of friction looks more like a drag force. The friction can be modeled by $\mu_r mg$ where $\mu_r$ is the coefficient of rolling resistance and m is the mass of the snooker ball.

There are plenty of small things being ignored in the analysis, though unimportant at lower velocities there is also a quadratic drag force, and the fact that the ball continually deforms the surface ever so slightly, furthermore the rolling friction you haven't modeled in your analysis.

Everyday experience tells us that real balls do not roll forever. If your model predicts that they do, the model is clearly wrong.

As already pointed out, your equation −() is that for air drag at low velocities. For kinetic friction the equation is $-\mu_{k}mg$. Also, you say no "spin" is involved. It's not clear if you mean no rolling is involved, just sliding along the surface? What's more, pure sliding will change to rolling once friction reduces the linear velocity to match the angular velocity so the condition for pure rolling occurs, i.e., $v=r\omega$. There are too many questions here.

"you would need to switch off the friction when the speed becomes zero" Yes, that is what happens.

Also, the force that slows down undriven rolling objects is NOT friction. It's rolling resistance.

Also, remember that the formula suggested above for friction ($\mu_rmg$) stops being valid as soon as velocity reaches zero, so it will never lead to the system going backwards (see Coulomb-Amonton laws).

I think it's important to take a step back and remember that these are all just (very simple) models.
You are referring to a cue ball rolling across a snooker table. Are you taking into account what the ball is made of, and what it's precise shape is (including micron-scale bumps and valleys)? Are you taking into account what the table is made of, its non-uniformities, and the dynamics of how the cue ball interacts with the felt fibers as it slides past them?
By modeling the friction force as $\mathbf F = - \alpha \mathbf v$, you are making the assumption that the force is simply linearly proportional to the velocity (when in fact it could be a nearly arbitrary function of both velocity and position) and that all of those aforementioned subtleties can be reasonably captured by a single number $\alpha$. This is a mind-bending approximation, and the fact that it works so well is genuinely remarkable (and not unrelated to Taylor's theorem).
The cost of this simplicity is that you might have to get your hands dirty by imposing an arbitrary cutoff. Perhaps you might say that as soon as your equations predict that the speed has slowed to less than 1 mm/s, you are going to set the velocity to zero. Perhaps, as advised in the comments, you add a kinetic friction term and then whenever the ball reaches zero speed, it stops forever.
As it turns out, finding a force law which results in your object stopping in finite time without "manual intervention" is a rather subtle business - I would encourage you to try to see what would be necessary for this as a fun little puzzle.

The snooker ball is subject to rolling resistance. This is proportional to coefficient of rolling resistance and the normal force (mg). Both factors are normally constants so rolling resistance is constant and independent of velocity as long as the velocity is non-zero. It is indeed an odd phenomena that the rolling resistance switches off as soon as the ball stops rolling but that it is what happens in reality. This constant force brings the ball to a stop in a finite time. For a billiard ball the rolling resistance can be thought of as the ball making an indentation in the felt table creating a little ramp that the ball has to continually climb up and the energy involved in compressing the surface. Rolling resistance is minimised by making both the rolling object and the surface as rigid as possible to minimise the indentation effect and to minimise the energy wasted in deformation of the object and surface. There are some other small forces that contribute to the rolling friction such as electrostatic attraction between the objects contact patch and the surface. Air resistance also contributes to the deceleration.
